# Accordion opens all panes instead of switching panes

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have code for an Accordion element in my website. I had this working as I wished, I clicked on header and the selected panel opens. When I click on another header, the previous pane closes and the selected pane open. Basic Accordion functionality. 
For some reason, without touching any of the code, this Accordion effect stopped working. Now, whenever I select a pane, it just opens. So if I select other panes, they will open as well but none will automatically close on opening another pane. So where did this go wrong,  I can't seem to find the error.
Here's the code:

```
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="item in All | unique:'gebieden'">
                        <div class="panel-heading text-center" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#{{$index}}">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                {{item.gebieden}}
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="{{$index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
                            <div class="panel-body text-center">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                    <li ng-repeat="sub in All | unique: 'onderwerpen'">
                                        <a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#{{sub.onderwerpen}}">
                                            {{sub.onderwerpen}}
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="tab-content" style="padding:2%">
                                    <div id="{{sub.onderwerpen}}" class="tab-pane fade">
                                        <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th class="text-center">Jaar</th>
                                                    <th class="text-center">Waarde</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr ng-repeat="(key,val) in item" ng-hide="$index<2" >
                                                    <td>{{key}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{val}}</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

So I just want the normal functionality back, being that there can only be 1 panel active at all times. Please help